# How add three numbers from three different tables in one row mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Im helping a friend with a query, these one needs show the percentage of each one of these tables: purchases, expenses and sales transactions in the month.

So I need show this:

---

Sales Percentage - Purchases Percentage - Expenses Percentage

```
  10%                   50%                   40%
```

---

One of the problems is these three tables dont have any type of relationship (foreign key).

To make these possible, obviously I must get the total of each one and add it to have the percentage base.

So, how can I add everything in a SELECT clausule?

Greetings.

Comment: Use sub query. select (select sum(...) from ...) as Sales_percentage, (select sum(...) from ... ) as Purchase _Percentage, (select sum(...) from ..) as expenses_percentage

Comment: @AnthonyChankokkiong thanks for answer, so to can use a subquery is something like this: select (select round(count(id_venta) / total * 100,2) from venta limit 1) as porcentaje_ventas

from
(
    select count(id_venta) as total from venta
    UNION ALL
    select count(id_compra) as total from compra
    UNION ALL
    select count(id_gastos) as total from gastos
) t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after so much thinking, I finally got it.

so this is the final answer, hope it can usefully:

```
select 
sum(total) as total_transacciones,
(select count(id_venta) from venta where fecha__venta between            '2019-01-01' and '2019-04-02') as total_ventas,
(select round((count(id_venta) / sum(total) * 100),2) from venta         where fecha__venta between '2019-01-01' and '2019-04-02') as  porcentaje_ventas,
(select count(id_compra) from compra where fecha_compra between '2019-01-01' and '2019-04-02') as total_compras,
(select round((count(id_compra) / sum(total) * 100),2) from compra where fecha_compra between '2019-01-01' and '2019-04-02') as porcentaje_compras,
(select count(id_gastos) from gastos where fecha_cr between '2019-01-01' and '2019-04-02') as total_gastos,
(select round((count(id_gastos) / sum(total) * 100),2) from gastos where fecha_cr between '2019-01-01' and '2019-04-02') as  porcentaje_gastos
from
(
select count(id_venta) as total from venta
UNION ALL
select count(id_compra) as total from compra
UNION ALL
select count(id_gastos) as total from gastos
) t
```

A capture from the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdkxP.png

Greetings.